# Wiring ceiling fan help diagam

Tags: wiring

I have a ceiling fan/light with remote. There are two single-pole switches that control each (fan/light). The fan works on the remote and from the switch.

The light works from the remote and from the switch, BUT the switch needs to be in the off position in order to have the remote dimmer work.

Currently wired as

- Ceiling red to black remote in
- Ceiling white to white remote in and remote out and to fan
- Ceiling black to blue remote out and fan
- Remote out black to black fan.

I'm guessing power is ran twice to the light, but can't figure it out. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome. Any thoughts about what? You haven't really asked a question.

Comment: Do you want the light controlled off the switch? Or off the remote? Note that switch control is a Code requirement if it’s the only light in the room.

Comment: Are you open to junking the remote that came with the fan and getting a different remote instead?